# Order By clause causing Performance Hit

Tags: sql, sorting, oracle11g, oracle12c

I've a SQL query that uses pipelined table function as below.

```
select col1,col2,... col75 from table(pipelinedtablefunction) 
order by col1
```

This query returns 100 000 records in 14 mins. If I remove the order by clause and execute the below query, the query runs in 1 second and retrieves same result.

```
select col1,col2,... col75 from table(pipelinedtablefunction)
```

I used order by clause inside pipelined function in the cursor query and I faced the same problem. Is there any way to resolve and improve the performance?

Comment: if your col1 indexed?

Comment: Yes , it is Indexed. The cursor query inside the pipe lined function is huge and complex but it goes like this.

select t1.col1,col2.. col75 from table1 t1, table2 t2
union all
select t11.col1,col2.. col75 from table11 t11, table12 t12

The Col1 in both t1 and t11 are primary key and it is indexed

Comment: Where is the explain plan? Also the code for pipelinedtablefunction would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, in one of the columns col50 , I've called a user defined function like below which actually executes for each row, that caused the time.

When I commented out that column from the select query, it runs within a second.

```
select col1,col2, ../*my_fun(col50)*/, col51.. col75 from table(pipelinedtablefunction) 
order by col1
```

We have tuned the function and now it is fine.